# External links doesn't work when running CSP

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I meet a surprising problem. If i don't enable my CSP config, no problem, everything works fine. But when I activate CSP, internal links work normally, but external not. On my website, (for example here, https://www.matosmaison.fr/avis/perceuses-visseuses/ryobi-rpd1200k) I have links to amazon, zanox and other similar. These links doesn't work when using CSP.

What is for you my mistake in this config ?

```
"csp": {
"defaultSrc": [
  "'self'",
  "www.matosmaison.fr",
  "cdn.matosmaison.fr",
  "www.google-analytics.com",
  "images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com",
  "youtube.com",
  "www.youtube.com",
  "googleads.g.doubleclick.net"
],
"scriptSrc": [
  "'self'",
  "www.matosmaison.fr",
  "cdn.matosmaison.fr",
  "www.google-analytics.com",
  "images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com",
  "youtube.com",
  "www.youtube.com",
  "googleads.g.doubleclick.net"
],
"styleSrc": [
  "'self'",
  "www.matosmaison.fr",
  "cdn.matosmaison.fr",
  "www.google-analytics.com",
  "images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com",
  "youtube.com",
  "www.youtube.com",
  "googleads.g.doubleclick.net",
  "'unsafe-inline'"
],
"fontSrc": [
  "'self'",
  "www.matosmaison.fr",
  "cdn.matosmaison.fr",
  "www.google-analytics.com",
  "images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com",
  "youtube.com",
  "www.youtube.com",
  "googleads.g.doubleclick.net",
  "'unsafe-inline'"
],
"imgSrc": [
  "'self'",
  "www.matosmaison.fr",
  "cdn.matosmaison.fr",
  "www.google-analytics.com",
  "images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com",
  "youtube.com",
  "www.youtube.com",
  "googleads.g.doubleclick.net",
  "data:"
],
"sandbox": ["allow-forms", "allow-scripts", "allow-same-origin", "allow-top-navigation"],
"reportUri": "/report-violation",
"objectSrc": []
```

}

I have tried with adding amazon, zanox and the others but no changes, it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Links to Amazon etc. work fine in my browser (Chrome 53.0.2785.116). Post the message you see in your browser console log (F12) and provide the browser version.

Comment: I have remove CSP headers, it's the production site ;)

Comment: Already tried the console. No errors at all (i have checked, there is no filter or other thing similar which can hide a message). Got it on chrome versions 52 and 53. Not experimenting it on Firefox 40.

Comment: Ok, I have found the "issue". It seems that the problem come from the attributes target of my links. If i don't have any target, no problem. If i have target="_blank", the link doesn't work (wtf?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution. Openning a new "_blank" tab is considered as opening a popup. So in sandbox mode, you can have this message

Blocked opening '[your link]' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

You can reproduce with the simple JS command :

`window.open('[your link]', '_blank')`

To fix it, you need to add this part :

`"sandbox": ["allow-popups"]`

or to complete the sandbox part with the value "allow-popups".